# The annotation x conflicts with a field on the model

Tags: django

I want to remove/replace some properties from list() call on Django rest framework call.
e.g. I have `ip_address` on the db table, also adds `ip_address` when perform_create() called, but it should not be shown/included on list() and retrieve() calls.

On retrieve calls, I can make it simply overriding the method then by adding `instance.ip_address = None`.

But the problem now I have is on list() calls, I need to modify properties of a queryset object.

I tried the following,

```py
o = ThreadedComment.objects.all()
o.annotate(ip_address=Value('', output_field=CharField())).all()
```

but I got an error:

```
The annotation 'ip_address' conflicts with a field on the model.
```

Is there a way to remove/override/replace an properly on queryset in Django? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with adding different name than the said one?

Comment: If you don't want specific column returned from DB, you can use .defer('ip_address')

Comment: @TrueGopnik Isn't .defer some kind of delayed db processing? I tried `ThreadedComment.objects.defer("ip_address")[0].ip_address`, but while it shouldn't return an IP e.g. "127.0.0.1" but None or error or something, it returns "127.0.0.1". Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @RajaSimon The problem is that even if I .annotate a different value instead of "ip_address" I would get "ip_address" contained in the http get responses. So I want to either 1. specify what to return on list() 2. remove unwanted properties on filter_queryset()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your question, In one of your views, for the `list()` and `retrive()` methods, you want `ip_address` not to be displayed or not to be in response for any reason. If I understand correctly for this purpose you have many solutions to do one of that is removing the field from the query set by the name of that field:

```py
fields_to_display = [field.name for field in ThreadedComment._meta.get_fields()]
fields_to_display.remove('ip_address')
qs = ThreadedComment.object.all().values(*fields_to_display)
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I put this workaround. Anyways works for me, but not sure this is the best I could do. Kindly tell me any hints or advices if you have some.

```py
def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        if self.context["request"].method == "GET": ret.pop("ip_address")
        return ret
```