# Django: the annotation field conflicts with a field on the model

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the below code using Django's `QuerySet` and `annotate`, in an attempt to`left join` 2 tables and replace `DocumentModel`'s column `description` with the result from another table `PackageModel` based on the `package_id`

```
        qs = DocumentModel.objects.filter(**some_filters).filter(s_query)

        packages = PackageModel.objects.filter(
            document_id=OuterRef("document__uuid")
        ).values("description")[:1]
        qs = qs.annotate(
            description=Coalesce(Subquery(packages), F("description")),
        )
```

However, I hit with the following error which is also correct. Both tables have the column `description`.

```
ValueError: The annotation 'description' conflicts with a field on the model.
```

I have try a few possible solutions, but I still can't get it to work.

**Option 1.**

Change from `description` to `package_description` in `qs.annotate()`, but that's not what I wanted. I actually want to replace the content from `PackageModel`.

**Option 2.**

Introduce a foreign-key, but the limitation prevents me from running other migration on this Django project. It also has existing content already in the `DocumentModel` description that we need to handle the deprecation separately, not in this change.

**Option 3.**

Following a suggestion from another Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73441295/618563), however, the result `QuerySet` would return as a `dict` which is not what we want. We want the return type stays the same as `DocumentModel`.

```
        fields = [field.name for field in DocumentModel._meta.get_fields()]
        fields.remove("description")
        qs = qs.values(*fields)
```

Does anyone have other good suggestions to handle this? And hopefully within the `QuerySet`, to maintain good efficient without having too much of heavy computation.

Comment: There is an open issue related to this : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28072
You could do it by using `.extra()` but you would need to write raw SQL.
Another approach would be to rename your field `description` and add a property on your model.